# Openpyxl ['MergedCell' object attribute 'hyperlink' is read-only] Problem

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

I met a problem while loading a xlsx File. In the worksheet there is a Hyperlink in a merged cell. While loading the file, error ocured. Can anybody
Code is just like this.

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(report_filepath)
```

Error Info:

```
    File "F:\mainfunc_new.py", line 733, in read_report
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(report_filepath)
  File "C:\Users\10225167\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 312, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\10225167\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 274, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\10225167\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 228, in read_worksheets
    ws_parser.bind_all()
  File "C:\Users\10225167\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 389, in bind_all
    self.bind_hyperlinks()
  File "C:\Users\10225167\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 355, in bind_hyperlinks
    cell.hyperlink = link
AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'hyperlink' is read-only
```

Thanks.

Comment: openpyxl doesn't have a file called `worksheet_reader.py`

Comment: worksheet_reader is just a function name in .../openpyxl/reader/excel.py. You can find this function in No. 205 Row of  excel.py.

Answer (score 5):

Use version 2.5.14 instead of yours. It worked for me.

```
pip install openpyxl==2.5.14
```

Comment: it saved my day!

Comment: solution for CONDA users for python3.5 which worked for me.`conda install -c conda-forge openpyxl=2.5.14 -y`

Answer (score 0):

Double check if the cells that you're merging are empty. I don't think you can merge cells if that has values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this error was caused by Excel format. I deleted the current excel file and replaced it with a good excel file,  the error disappeared.